# Is it possible to rewrite this restart script on one line?

Tags: debian, bash, service

I wonder if it is possible to rewrite this script below on one line? Probably with `||` ?

```
ps auxw | grep nagios-nrpe-server | grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start > /dev/null
fi
```

I tryed `ps auxw | grep nagios-nrpe-server | grep -v grep > /dev/null || /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start` but it restart service all the time, even if it is running..

Comment: Dump the ancient init script and use a proper systemd unit, which can automatically restart the server if it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pgrep`:

```
pgrep nrpe > /dev/null || /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start > /dev/null
```

or using a subshell:

```
(pgrep nrpe || /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start) > /dev/null
```

From the `pgrep(1)` manpage:

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout.

If the process name is not `nrpe`, you need to replace the argument to `pgrep` with the actual process name.

Comment: same problem..even when is Nagios running output from this is 
[ ok ] Starting nagios-nrpe-server (via systemctl): nagios-nrpe-server.service.

Comment: You need to redirect the init script to `/dev/null` also.  One way is `pgrep nagios-nrpe-server > /dev/null || /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start > /dev/null`.  Or use a subshell: `(pgrep nagios-nrpe-server || /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start) > /dev/null`

Comment: @chicks  Yes, you are correct. That solves the OP's spurious output issue. Modified my answer.

Comment: Piping the output of the init script to `null` only suppresses a symptom of the problem, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider What problem needs solving?

Comment: @fpmurphy The problem that the line still starts the service even when it's already running.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider.  How does your solution, i.e.  `ps auxw | grep -v grep | grep nrpe`, solve that issue?

Comment: as is @GeraldSchneider saying, problem is that service is starting even if it is already running. Thats not quite okay I think..

Comment: @Delirium  I agree. What is the output of `pgrep -l nrpe` when the server is running?

Comment: @fpmurphy 15914 nrpe

Comment: @Delirium.  Sigh, guess your check, i.e. `ps auxw | grep nagios-nrpe-server | grep -v grep > /dev/null` never worked!  Modified my answer to use `npre` instead of `nagios-nrpe-server`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch your grep statements. Your second statement to filter out `grep` will always succeed, because it is always there.

So, first filter out grep and then check for the process:

```
ps auxw | grep -v grep | grep nrpe > /dev/null || /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start
```

According to the [Debian package list](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/nagios-nrpe-server/filelist) the binary of the nagios-nrpe-server is just called `nrpe`, so I substituted that.

Comment: but if I switch it, service is always started over and over again, same as in my try.. Should not be in that one liner some check if output is "0" ?

Comment: `||` is the check if the return code is `0`. In my tests the line works as I wrote it.

Comment: Are you sure the string `nagios-nrpe-server` shows up in `ps`? It's been a while since I used nagios, but IIRC the process had a different name.

Comment: According to the [debian package list](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/nagios-nrpe-server/filelist) the binary is just called `nrpe`.